# How do you run the main binary and then run tests based on it in Rust?

Tags: testing, rust, rust-cargo

I have written a webserver which requires some complicated setup and teardown, and am trying to write unit tests. Axum does provide examples using the Tower OneShot function, but these don't easily allow the full flow of the setup. How would I run the full server, and then run additional code to test it (using reqwest) with `cargo test`?

Comment: what kind of webserver? what is your goal of your testing in this case

Comment: a REST API server, the goal is to test out all of the possible user-triggerable errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `the_real_deal` in this example https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/blob/main/examples/testing/src/main.rs

Comment: Can this be run during other tests, or do i just need to pack each of my tests into a single function?

Comment: You can write multiple test functions like this.

Answer (score 5):

The [CLI book](https://rust-cli.github.io/book/tutorial/testing.html) has a nice approach shown:

```ini
# add this to your Cargo.toml
[dev-dependencies]
assert_cmd = "2.0"
predicates = "2.1"
```

Then you can write a test like this:

```rust
// tests/cli.rs

use assert_cmd::prelude::*; // Add methods on commands
use predicates::prelude::*; // Used for writing assertions
use std::process::Command; // Run programs

#[test]
fn file_doesnt_exist() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut cmd = Command::cargo_bin("your-binary-name")?;

    cmd.arg("foobar").arg("test/file/doesnt/exist");
    cmd.assert()
        .failure()
        .stderr(predicate::str::contains("could not read file"));

    Ok(())
}
```

The main essence is this `Command::cargo_bin("your-binary-name")?`

That is [documented in the `assert_cmd` crate](https://docs.rs/assert_cmd/latest/assert_cmd/cargo/index.html)

That allows you to call your binary from a test, without the need to compile it first, cargo takes care of it.

Comment: Admitted this is more a general approach on how to integration test a binary. For axum in particular the [test example in their repo](https://github.com/tokio-rs/axum/blob/main/examples/testing/src/main.rs#L73) is a good starting point.